# Metric space where isometries don't satisfy a property

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Find a metric space $X$, where for $x,y\in X$ every isometry f on $X$ satisfies $f(x)\neq y$.

I thought of considering the sets with a finite classification of isometries, such as the real plane with the standard metric, where every isometry is either a left or right translation, but that got me nowhere. I also thought of space which are discrete. May I have hints?

Comment: You should edit your question to clarity what freakish pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "for $x,y\in X$". Is it "for each $x,y\in X$"? Then no such space can exist. But if you mean "for each $x,y\in X$ such that $x\neq y$" then basically you are looking for a space such that the only isometry is the identity.

Consider $X=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ and note that $[0,1]$ has only two isometries, namely $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto 1-x$. So I've added $2$ to $[0,1]$ to get rid of $x\mapsto 1-x$ isometry. And so the only isometry on $[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ is the identity $x\mapsto x$.

For a connected example consider the boundary of a triangle of (pairwise) unequal sides.